# Lower optimum temperature of plant Catalase

Tags: enzymes, temperature

Most resources give an optimum temperature of 35° C for Catalase. after performing the AP Catalase enzyme lab in school, using blended potatoes, our results gave a greater reaction rate at a room temperature of 25° C. we hypothesized that this is due to the fact that potatoes cannot regulate body temperature, so catalase works better at room temperature. The only source we could find that backed up its claim was an excerpt from a Pearson textbook: [Here](https://assets.pearsonglobalschools.com/asset_mgr/current/201214/HeinemannIGCSE_Biology_chapter3.pdf)

Do plants have a lower optimum temperature like the textbook suggests, or was something wrong in our experiment?

(75 students, half did potatoes, half did liver)

Comment: There are two points you need to do here. 1. Tell us clearly what the results were for catalase from the two sources. You do not do this and therefore I cannot see what you are trying to explain. Please rewrite it. 2. Find whether your results contradict published results. Although the generalization in Pearson is reasonable, it need not apply to all enzymes. There is no reason why an enzyme in an organism that metabolizes at ambient temperature might have greater activity at a higher temperature that it never encounters. I can’t see this being selected against.